# Why is it important to specify interface when setting a permanent arp entry?

Tags: linux, networking

When setting a permanent arp entry you specify the L3 and L2 address as well as the device. E.g.

```
ip neighbor add 192.168.0.3 lladdr 02:42:c0:a8:00:03 dev vxlan1
```

The ip-neighbour man page defines the device as 'the interface to which this neighbour is attached'. I don't understand why it is important that the neighbour table maintains what device a neighbour is associated with. I would have thought that would be the responsibility of the routing table and the neighbour table is just L3->L2 mappings. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routing table contains only the the **gateway** to be used for different interfaces.

In the meantime the Arp tables is Layer 3 to Layer 2 resolution having a mapping between **Mac** & **IP addresses.**

There is also the mac address table that is only use by switches that contains the mapping between **Ports** and **Mac Addresses.**

So it's normal that with adding an ARP entry you have to specify a **NIC device** which will have a Mac Address needed for **L3 / L2** mapping.

Comment: OK this makes sense. My confusion was I didn't realize arp tables were maintained separately on each device/interface. Thanks!